# How to Remove Scene from SKView?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

How does one remove a scene out of the SKView. I've called removeFromParent, set the scene to nil, just about everything I can think of yet the scene is still displayed.

Comment: How did you set the scene to nil? Did you use presentScene:nil?

Comment: Yes, however it only disables everything about the scene. The actual scene is still visible though @AndreyChernukha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I was removing a scene was correct, it was the Pause feature that of `scene.view.paused = true`. This caused the presenting of new scenes or the removal of old scenes to not work correctly. For those that use this line of code just go with `scene.paused` instead.